# Fullcalendar customizing the Agenda display

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to make three changes to the fullcalendar Agenda view.

1. Remove start time from events, essentially I just want to display the title in each slot.
2. Change the height of timeslots, I have tried adjusting the contentHeight but that had no apparent effect.
3. Show 30min slots on Y-axis, I know about axisFormat option but it still only displays the full hours.

If anyone can give me any suggestions on how to accomplish these 3 changes?

Comment: try editing the plugin, it's easier than you think.. That is the only way you can have what you wish,,

Comment: @Prasanthchinja Thanks I'll have a look at that

Comment: 1 and 3 are easy with configuration or little code. For point 2 I think you need to add some custom CSS. Did you resolve your issues already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fullcalendar have rich callback set to configure:

1. You should use [eventRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) to modify it (hide title in already constructed is best way of it). Do not try construct new element and replace original
2. The same `eventRender` where you can add CSS or class and then change per event or direct from CSS
3. Agenda view does not have time slots at all, it is time-ordered list which does not represent proportion of time-lenght between events. If you wan't time based view, then try singe day view and set [slotDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/) as close as you want, even on the fly with buttons or keybind. + when setting `slotDuration`, if you wan't support adding events, change also [snapDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/snapDuration/)